# How to set metricbeat on amazon elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch, metricbeat

I have two servers one for production and one for test, I've been trying to install metricbeat on both servers.
I did on my test server and set it to send logs to my amazon elasticsearch service and now I can see on kibana all data from that server but I did the same process to my production server and when I use command sudo metricbeat -e it starts but I get
 ERROR   pipeline/output.go:74   Failed to connect: Get https://amazon-endpoint  request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) but the config for both is the same

Comment: your production server could not connect to amazon elasticsearch

Comment: Check Amazon Elasticsearch domain access policy and see if your production server is whitelisted. From production server are you able to curl AWS ES URL and see a successful response ?

Comment: yes, I'm able to curl my amazon URL with a successful response

Comment: Then metricbeat should also be able to connect unless something wrong in metricbeat config

Comment: sorry guys I did a curl test in other server , I tried curl on production but does not work just work on my test server

Comment: Check AWS ES domain access policy and see if your production server is whitelisted ? Are you using a single AWS ES domain for both test & prod or separate ?

Comment: Thanks guys my problem was a whitelisted